# djangocms custom plugin duplicating behavior

Tags: python-2.7, plugins, django-cms, django-1.6

I have a simple custom djangocms plugin that acts strangely upon publishing changes.

The full code is in this repo: https://github.com/creimers/djangocms_sociallist

This is the model:

```
class SocialList(CMSPlugin):

    name = models.CharField(
        'Liste',
        blank=False,
        default='',
        max_length=32,
    )

def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    for associated_item in oldinstance.associated_item.all():
        associated_item.pk = None
        associated_item.plugin = self
        associated_item.save()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name


class SocialIcon(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('fa-facebook', 'facebook'),
        ('fa-google-plus', 'google-plus'),
        ('fa-twitter', 'twitter'),
        ('fa-instagram', 'instagram'),
        ('fa-yelp', 'yelp'),
        ('fa-youtube-play', 'youtube'),
        ('fa-foursquare', 'foursquare'),
    )
    social_list = models.ForeignKey(
        SocialList,
        related_name="associated_item"
    )
    icon = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        choices=choices,
    )
    link = models.URLField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.icon
```

This is the `cms_plugins.py`:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SocialIcon
    extra = 1


class SocialPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    name = u'Social Icons'
    model = SocialList
    render_template = "djangocms_sociallist/_social_plugin.html"
    #form = SocialListPluginAdminForm
    inlines = [ChoiceInline, ]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        items = instance.associated_item.all()
        context.update({
            'items': items,
            'instance': instance,
        })
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(SocialPlugin)
```

And this is the template:

```
<div class="social-list-container">
    <ul class="social-list">
        {% for icon in items %}
        <a href="{{icon.link}}">
            <li class="social-list-item">
                <i class="fa {{icon.icon}}"></i>
            </li>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

In draft mode, everything works as I'd expect. Strange things happen when I hit 'publish changes'.

This is in draft mode. I have added three icons. The icon list is called 'test' and can be seen in the left admin sidebar.

[image: DRAFT MODE]

Then, after switching to 'live', the icons don't show. Also, the 'test' list has duplicated in the admin panel.

[image: LIVE MODE]

Switching back to 'draft', the two lists with the same name are rendered in the plugin template.

[image: BACK TO DRAFT]

Admittedly new to django(cms) and its concepts, I don't quite know what to make of this. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can give a partial answer to my question:

`associated_item.plugin = self` should have been `associated_item.social_list = self`, of course. I simply forgot to plug in the name of my specific model reference.

So this is what my `copy_relations` looks like now:

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    for associated_item in oldinstance.associated_item.all():
        associated_item.pk = None
        associated_item.social_list = self
        associated_item.save()
```

I can now publish my plugin and it doesn't disappear.

### Concerning the duplicating behavior:

#### The issue I think is that I've been messing where I shouldn't have been messing.

I take the same model (inheriting from `CMSPlugin`) and reference it both in `admin.py` and `cms_plugins.py`. Instead, I think I should have done something like this:

```
class SocialList(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        'Liste',
        blank=False,
        default='',
        max_length=32,
    )

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for associated_item in oldinstance.associated_item.all():
            associated_item.pk = None
            associated_item.social_list = self
            associated_item.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

    class SocialListPlugin(CMSPlugin):

        list = models.ForeignKey(SocialList)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.list.name
```

Hence a separation of concerns.

That's my conclusion after digging through other peoples plugins on github and analyzing how they bind models to `admin` and `cms_plugins`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.